# Code Igniter: Resolve dependencies for Windows Azure Storage Tools

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, azure-storage

I am using windows azure blob storage for storing data that the users will upload to my website. My websites has been developed using the Code Igniter framework and as per the documentation for [Blob Service for PHP](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/#ConfigureStorage):

> This example (and other examples in this article) assume you have
>   installed the PHP Client Libraries for Windows Azure via Composer. If
>   you installed the libraries manually or as a PEAR package, you will
>   need to reference the WindowsAzure.php autoloader file.

How do incorporate those Pear Packages into Code Igniter to make sure that these dependencies remain resolved? I tried putting them in the libraries folder but that didn't work as I would need to load them every time they are used. I even tried setting them to autoload but without any avail.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working! Install those dependencies on the root folder of the website. And also copy the PEAR package folder to the root.